# How do you create domain redirect in Laravel htaccess but not on page alias

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I have a domain alias that I want to stay as it is, but I want to redirect the main domain url.

http(and s)://www.alias.maindomain.com -> no redirect

http(and s)://www.maindomain.com -> redirect to given url

I have a Laravel project and this is my htacess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^http://www.maindomain.com"  "http://www.redirectedpage.com"
```

I tried redirecting the routes in laravel but that wasnt working so think the htacess file is the way to go?

Comment: Is that all URLs on the maindomain? Or literally just the root? What is the "given URL" you want to redirect to? (The [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) state that the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against a URL-path, this doesn't include the scheme and hostname.)

Comment: thanks @MrWhite, but not exactly sure what you're asking. I want to redirect from http://www.maindomain.com to http://www.redirectedpage.com.

Comment: What about `www.maindomain.com/something`?

Comment: @MrWhite yep that exists. i see, so yes, I want it redirected for just the root, not for alias pages or sub pages. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect *only* `www.maindomain.com/` to `https://www.redirectpage.com/` you would need to do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, before the Laravel directives.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.maindomain.com
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.redirectpage.com/ [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (the first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive) matches the requested URL-path only (less the directory-prefix when used in a `.htaccess` context, so there is no slash prefix). In this case, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^$` matches an *empty* URL-path, corresponding to the requested URL `/` (ie. the document root).

To match the requested *hostname* you need to use a *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and check against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable - which contains the value of the `Host` HTTP request header.

The *CondPattern* `=www.maindomain.com` (with a `=` prefix) is an exact match string comparison, not a regex.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule "^http://www.maindomain.com"  "http://www.redirectedpage.com"
> ```

I'm not sure why you are checking that the request does not map to a physical file. If you want to redirect a specific URL, then it presumably does not matter  whether that URL maps to a file (or directory).

As mentioned above, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the requested URL-path. So, the regex `^http://www.maindomain.com` will never match.